# Why does Resharper not recognise my web references?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I've just installed Resharper to do an evaluation on it. I have a solution with 28 projects in it and it seems to help with the coding and has pointed out several potential issues. However...

I've created several webservices (with in this solution) using the standard Visual Studio projects. I reference these webservices in other web projects - the code compiles fine and runs without problem. However, Resharper doesn't recognise these web references and treats them as errors. E.g. for a line of code referencing my ToolsWebService service as below

```
ToolsWS.ToolsWebService toolsWS = new ToolsWS.ToolsWebService();
```

I get an error

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'ToolsWS'
```

I can't post all of the code here - so I'm looking for any hints or tips that will pint me in the right direction

I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2005 with Resharper v4.5.1274.1

---

I've had to uninstall Resharper as I couldn't fix this issue. It stopped me from using Visual Studio for any classes using the web references. This is a shame because everyone seems to love Resharper

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had to uninstall Resharper as I couldn't fix this issue. It stopped me from using Visual Studio for any classes using the web references. This is a shame because everyone seems to love Resharper

I couldnt accept gsharp's answer as it didnt fix my issue - I have voted it up though. If anyone knows a better way I can resolve how I've closed this question, please let me know

Comment: It's a PITA. It took me a few hours of trying to "fix" my project, before I found this question with the same issue. I now either ignore it, or sometimes disable Resharper. Don't want to lost my Resharper permanently!

Comment: Also reported @ http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5310364 (seems like JetBrains' QA department cannot reproduce. Aaaargh!)

Answer (score 6):

R# has problems sometimes with the WebReferences.

Try Menu ReSharper --> Options --> General --> Clear Caches

sometimes it helps to restart Visual Studio as well.

Comment: Tried this but didn't work. Do you think its to do with the Solution Wide analysis being on - I've seen some posts saying this has issues

Comment: I don't think so. Have also a look here.. http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/RSRP-58820

Comment: @gsharp Your link is no longer valid (404)

Comment: @JeroenK https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-58820 is the new link. However the new r# version should have that problem fixed..